# 200A 240V Electric Panel Clearance

Tags: electrical-panel, nec

I am installing an electric panel. NEC 110.26A providing for 30" x 36" x 6'6" is met ***EXCEPT*** for the main water supply line which will runs against the wall and underneath it at floor level. There is no other equipment. Is there no way around this problem?

@ThreePhaseEel Surface mount. I thought about rerunning the pipe over the panel to clear the 6'6". But the idea of putting a water line above the panel is just wrong!

Comment: Is this a surface-mounted or a flush-mounted panel?

Comment: Surface mount panel

Comment: Going directly under or over is going to  give problems with 110.26(E)(1)(a), depth and width of panel from floor to 6 ft. above panel or structural ceiling.

Comment: What sort of wall construction is the panel mounted to?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Brick

Answer (score 2):

This requirement is to provide a good clean standing area when accessing it.

If the inspector would give you flack for it (call them in advance whether they would) you can build out the bit of wall the electric panel is mounted to such that the water line is actually under the panel inside the wall instead of in front.

Comment: I may mount a backing plate first so that the panel is never actually "over" water line!